# 500 Internal error in oidc authentication redirect callback using passportJS, only happens deployed in cloud, works when hosted on localhost

Tags: oauth, callback, passport.js, openid-connect

Thank you in advance I have searched in forum, did not find good answers.

I have a simple authentication service implemented with passportJS and openid-client, everything works fine when the service is hosted locally (`http://localhost:4021`), but I get an http 500 internal server error on the "redirect callback" when deployed on AWS cloud which has an https URL.

My debug shows it never returns to the Strategy callback  when the 500 error is thrown. Strategy is imported from "openid-client".

I have doubled checked the redirect URL config, it looks good.

Here is my service code for authentication:

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
 .......
const client = new oidcIssuer.Client({
    client_id: myID,
    client_secret: mySecret,
    redirect_uris: [`${MY_ENDPOINT}/auth/callback`],
    response_types: ['code']
});

client[custom.clock_tolerance] = 5;

passport.use('oidc',
    new Strategy({ client, passReqToCallback: true }, async (req, tokenSet, userinfo, done) => {
        accUserInfo = userinfo;
        return done(null, tokenSet); 
    })
);

const options = {
    scope: openid
};

passport.authenticate('oidc', options)(req, res,
(err) => {
    next();
});
});
```

Here is my handler for the callback:

```
app.get('/auth/callback', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('in the callback');
});
```

Everything works fine when the service is hosted locally (`http://localhost:4021`), but I get an http 500 internal server error on the "redirect callback" when deployed on the cloud which has an https URL.

Comment: To follow up, I just noticed the passport.use() got called multiple times when running on AWS, but only called once when running from locahost.  Is this a problem???

Comment: Facing same issue. Did you get anything?